# Difference between  割合 vs 率

Tags: word-choice, usage, vocabulary, nuances, kanji

割合  and  率 both mean ratio, rate, and percentage. What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither means percentage. Percentage is one hundred times ratio or rate. The Japanese word for it is `百分率`. Likewise, permillion is one million times ratio or rate. The Japanese word for it is `百万分率`.

My impression is that `割合` and `ratio` are the general terms for a quantity divided by another quantity (usually but not always of the same dimension). `率` and `rate` are especially for cases where its lowness or highness is connected to its preferred amount in an ideal situation. For example, `率` or `rate` is used for `誤差~` or `error ~` because the ideal case would be zero. It can be also used for `正解~` or `correctness ~` because the ideal situation will be one. It is also used in `転送~` or `bit ~` because the larger the better.

Comment: @ZarNge Accept the answer, please? Click on the "tick" on the left of the answer, which will turn green when you highlight it.

Answer (score 2):

these two words literally share the similar meanings of ratio,rate.
translation of the the explaination from the [yahoo 知惠袋 website](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1410443619)

割合 normally is used to refer to the proportion of sth,the relationship of one thing to another in size, amount, etc.

eg: 1. The proportion of men to women in the college has changed dramatically over the years. 
近年学校の男女の割合を大きく変化しています。

```
 2. Limestone and clay in the proportion 2: 1.  
石灰石と粘土の割合は２対１also :
石灰石と粘土の比率は２対１
```

率 is often used after a sort of noun in order to express the percent of ...;for instance percentage "百分率", percent of pass "合格率", percent of attendance "出勤率" etc.
and as mentioned above, when use with "比" as"比率", 比率shall substitute "割合".

Comment: Your first example is ungrammatical. You are wrong in that `合格率` etc. does not mean percentage by itself, although it can be measured in terms of percentage.